# Bootstrap 3 - CSS Align Content

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3, sass

Hello Im trying to achieve this look, but I'm not very good with positioning with css.

Im using bootstrap 3 as a framework too. I don't think I'm too far off!

What I need:

[image]

What I have:

[image]

Code: (Using SASS As a pre-complier)

```css
.top-footer {
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(../img/footerBG.png);
 color: $white;
 padding: 50px 5em;
 
 .col-head {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  h3 {
   font-size: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
 }

 .col-content {
  font-family: $font-family;
  float: right;
  
  img {
   padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .latest-news {

   h4 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 600;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   }

   p {
    position: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px
   }
   
   a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: $primary;
    font-size: 14px;

    &:hover {
     color: darken($primary, 15%)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-head">
    <h3>Recent News</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/recent-news.png">
    <div class="latest-news">
      <h4>Latest Updates</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam venenatis faucibus nisi... </p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bootstrap inbuilt class to achieve the same effect

```
<div class="col-content">
 <div class="row">
   <div class="col-md-4">
     <img src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/recent-news.png">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8">
     <div class="latest-news">
       <h4>Latest Updates</h4>
       <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam venenatis faucibus nisi... </p>
       <a href="#">Read More</a>
     </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Works Great! Just have to float the image to the left!

Answer (score 0):

HI now define your `img` `tag` and your `.latest-news` class `display` `inline-block` as like this

```
.latest-news {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.col-content > img{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
}
.latest-news > h4{margin:0;}
```

**Demo**

```css
.latest-news {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.col-content > img{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}.latest-news > h4{margin:0;}
.top-footer {
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(../img/footerBG.png);
 color: $white;
 padding: 50px 5em;
 
 .col-head {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  h3 {
   font-size: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
 }

 .col-content {
  font-family: $font-family;
  float: right;
  
  img {
   padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .latest-news {

   h4 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 600;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   }

   p {
    position: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px
   }
   
   a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: $primary;
    font-size: 14px;

    &:hover {
     color: darken($primary, 15%)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-head">
    <h3>Recent News</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a81b631d141dd86d72fc12419f0a3b26?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <div class="latest-news">
      <h4>Latest Updates</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam venenatis faucibus nisi... </p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.col-md-4
{
   border:1px solid gray;
  padding:10px;
}
.latest-news {
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}
.col-content > img{
display: inline-block;
vertical-align: top;
}.latest-news > h4{margin:0;}
.top-footer {
 position: relative;
 background-image: url(../img/footerBG.png);
 color: $white;
 padding: 50px 5em;
 
 .col-head {
  font-weight: 600;
  text-transform: uppercase;

  h3 {
   font-size: 1em;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   letter-spacing: 2px;
  }
 }

 .col-content {
  font-family: $font-family;
  float: right;
  
  img {
   padding-top: 15px;
  }
  .latest-news {

   h4 {
   text-transform: uppercase;
   font-weight: 600;
   letter-spacing: 1px;
   font-size: 14px;
   margin-bottom: 5px;
   }

   p {
    position: block;
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 5px
   }
   
   a {
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: 600;
    color: $primary;
    font-size: 14px;

    &:hover {
     color: darken($primary, 15%)
    }
   }
  }
 }
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-4">
  <div class="col-head">
    <h3>Recent News</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="col-content">
    <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a81b631d141dd86d72fc12419f0a3b26?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG&f=1">
    <div class="latest-news">
      <h4>Latest Updates</h4>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam venenatis faucibus nisi... </p>
      <a href="#">Read More</a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```